# print even numbers program only prints 4

Tags: python, variables

```
n = 1
a = 2
num = 2*a*n
while n <= 100:
    print (num)
    n = n+1
```

I want to print even number between 1< num <= 100
but, computer prints only 4

Answer (score 0):

Because you calculate the value for `num` only once `num = 2*a*n //= 4` . So you just print `n-times` the value 4. If you want to recalculate it you have to put it inside the loop

```
while n <= 100
    num = 2*a*n
    print (num)
    n = n+1
```

Be patient that i just reused your pseudo code syntax

Answer (score 0):

In your solution , num is not changing , it keeps on value 4 
So you should change it on every iteration :

```
    n=1
    a=2
   num=2*a*n //here num=4

   while n<=100 
     print (num) 
     n=n+1
     num=2*a*n //so that now num is changed
```

Good luck